# Converting from a PHP MySQL result object to a result resource (OO to procedural)

Tags: php, mysql, object

I have been handling MySQL database functions within a PHP application using an object oriented style.  But now I want to use a function that requires a result resource as an input variable but all I have available is a result object from the statement

```
          $oresult = $odb->query($sql);
```

Is there a way to produce a result resource from an object oriented style database connection 
($dbconn = new mysqli (...))?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to provide the resource to your result set (wrapper functions to encapsulate the database functions. I.e., numRows(), affectedRows(), etc.), which in turn can provide you with a record set to iterate the results if necessary.

Comment: I'm reading your response and struggling to gain a basic understanding.  How do I "provide the resource to [my] result set"?  Are you suggesting that the drop the OO style so that I have a resource or is there a way to gain a result resource?  If the latter can you give an example?  Sorry if I'm missing something simple.

Comment: I'll have to split this over multiple replies, since I have a maximum character limit to work around.Let me demonstrate with a little code. 

Lets assume we have a Mysql_Query class which performs either select, update, or delete the specified SQL statements.

Comment: class Mysql_Query
{
   public function select($sql) 
   {
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
   
      return new Mysql_Result($result);
   }
}

class Mysql_Result {
   protected $_resource;
 
   public function __construct($resource) {
      $this->_resource = $resource;
   }
   
   public function numRows() {
      return mysql_num_rows($this->_resource);
   }
   
   public function fetchRows() {
      $rows = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->_result)) {
         $rows[] = $row; 
      }
      return $rows;
   }
}

Comment: As you can see, you never want to directly have the resource available publicly. Instead, you want to encapsulate the logic of the mysql* methods that require the resource, and pass the resource to them internally. In this simple example, you'll see I pass the result of mysql_query() to a result class, which exposes mysql functions and is given internally the resource for the executed query.

Comment: John, Thanks for writing out the example code.  I needed to see the "wrapping" in action before it fully made sense.  After reading this and Bob's response I decided to bite the bullet and rewrite my function to accept a resource object. - Tom

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, both OO and Procedural styles of Mysqli do not even deal out result resources at all.  The `query()` and `real_query()` functions and methods all immediately (or eventually lead to) return a `Mysqli_result` *object* if a recordset is returned.  There is no function or property throughout the Mysqli extension to extract the "link" from the main `Mysqli` object, nor to extract the resource (per se) from the `Mysqli_result` object.  In fact, that `$link` you see referenced throughout the procedural style examples of Mysqli is actually just a `Mysqli` object.

If any function you're using calls for a "result resource", they would have to mean coming from a function of the old, regular Mysql extension.  There is no way to blend Mysql and Mysqli functions and methods together.  So essentially, yes, you would have to forgo Mysql***i*** entirely in this case, and start with old-style, procedural Mysql from the very beginning.

Comment: As I noted below, after reading this clarification of the complete separation of Mysql and Mysqli function I decided that I could rewrite my existing function to accept the result object as an incoming variable.  Thanks for your response. - Tom

Comment: @Tom T: No problem. You probably have a good idea there making a function or class handle both mysqli and mysql if you're developing some sort of bridging framework between old and new. There is potential in designing your own way to make them seamlessly work together especially on an old website that chose the old MySQL route. Otherwise, be cautious of similar extensions and plugins, where sometimes functions and classes can be interchanged (exceptions, spl exceptions), and sometimes not (mysql, mysqli).